# SQL using LIKE operator with variable

Tags: sql, sql-like

I'm trying to search and update columns in my database by the value of a string variable:

```
sprintf(query, "UPDATE Vote "
"SET choice = '%s' "
"WHERE choice LIKE '%'%s'%'", newVote, originalVoteContains);
```

how can I use a variable of type string in the LIKE operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use double percent signs to escape the percent signs in the string, and remove the extra apostrophes around the value:

```
sprintf(query, "UPDATE Vote "
"SET choice = '%s' "
"WHERE choice LIKE '%%%s%%'", newVote, originalVoteContains);
```